# SQLAlchemy update and fetch in the same operation

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to run an update and return the updated results from the same query.

My problems with doing it in two steps

**1) Data queried twice by two instances** I have workers that could be querying the same database so I can't have a split second where the same query ran on another instance before my first instance got a chance to update the results. If I do the update first and then the select after there is a chance the same records could be queried by another instance.

**2) Memory** Since I first query to get the record ids then pass the record ids to the update query, i'm loading all this data in memory which could be a problem depending on the amount queried.

Two part query

```
# Select
results = cls.query.filter(
    MyModel.section_id == section_id,
    MyModel.mode = 0,
    MyModel.created_at < timest
).order_by(
    desc(MyModel.created_at)
).all()

# Update
model_ids = [x.id from x in results]
cls.query.filter(MyModel.id.in_(model_ids)).update(dict(mode = 1), synchronize_session='fetch')
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: All this code is running in the same transaction (assuming sensible isolation settings), so the select/update race shouldn't be a problem?  Then you could use [Query.with_for_update](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html?highlight=for_update#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_for_update) to prevent another instance performing an update?

Comment: Hey I'm not currently explicitly using a transaction. Thanks for with_for_update info! I didn't know about it and will look into it, it does seem like it could solve the issue!

Comment: Actually and if I understand correctly this might not be efficient enough for this use case. Since I can't issue another update command while the rows are locked that means I have to modify the models that were returned in the first select "with update" command, update the properties, then commit. Since I'm dealing with hundreds of records that would mean it would submit 100+ queries on commit that could have been done with 1 update commit.

Comment: The session already creates a transaction see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_transaction.html#transactions-and-connection-management